# once webpage load I want to select radio button of webpage using android java code using webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, radio-button

I want to select the `RadioButton` on a webpage using a `WebView` with my android java code. I can post data by loading `javascript` inside `webview.load()`. But now I want to know how to click or select the `RadioButton` in a webpage using `WebView` once the page loaded.

I tried all possible way that I get from the internet.

this is my webpage RadioButton`enter code here` code

```
<input type="radio" name="leave_type" id="leave_type1" value="Half Day" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

this is my android code and Javascript already enabled

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){                                                         

    @Override                                                         
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

    webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('leave_type1').click();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('leave_type1').checked='0';";
```